# Downloading Images Using Python Ending Up with Question Mark When Saving

Tags: python

I have the following Python script that reads the image urls from a text file and then downloads the images and saves it in the same folder. The images are downloaded file but for some reason

```
# this script is used to download the images using the provided url
import requests
import ntpath


# save image data
def save_image_data(image_data,file_name):
    with open(file_name,'wb') as file_object:
        file_object.write(image_data)

# read the images_url file
with open('images_urls_small.txt') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        file_name = ntpath.basename(line)
        print(file_name)
        # download the image
        try:
            image_data = requests.get(line).content
        except:
            print("error download an image")
        # save the image
        save_image_data(image_data,file_name)
```

The images are downloaded fine but for reason it ends up with ? after their file name as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `print(ascii(file_name))` in the `save_image_data` function show? It is almost certainly the newline (so `\n`) at the end; strip those off.

Comment: Thanks! Yes you are right that was it. If you can put that as an answer I can accept it as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You taking the filenames from a file:

```
for line in file_object:
    file_name = ntpath.basename(line)
```

but those lines will still have the line separator (a newline character, so `\n`) inscluded. Strip your lines:

```
for line in file_object:
    file_name = ntpath.basename(line.strip())
```